# Confusing Javascript prototype works

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

```
function A() {
 this.width=50;
 this.container = '#container';
}
function B() {
  this.width = 999;
  A.call(this)
}
var ball = new B()
ball.width = 50
```

I understand b.width = 50. What If I want to have width as 999? I want to borrow only "container" property value.

Comment: For that very reason parent constructors must be called *before* you work with the instance members.

Comment: Ah. Silly me Thanks @zerkms